# Ruby / SASS / RVM

Tags: ruby

I've installed ruby 2.3.1 on RHEL 5, using RVM.

I've also installed SASS.

```
-bash-3.2$ which ruby
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby
```

And

```
-bash-3.2$ which sass
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/sass
```

And

```
-bash-3.2$ gem which sass
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass.rb
```

However, when I try to use SASS via a php script, I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:319:in `to_specs': Could not find 'sass' (>= 0.a) among 16 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/.gem/ruby/2.3.0:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0', execute `gem env` for more information
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:328:in `to_spec'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:65:in `gem'
    from /usr/bin/sass:22:in `<main>'
    from /usr/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /usr/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Running gem environment gempath yields:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1
```

You can see that there is conflicting information regarding the GEM_PATH in the error message, and the value shown above for the environment gempath.

I suspect there's some remnants of a previous version of ruby that are causing issues, but at this point i'm drawing a blank.

The entire results of calling gem env are below:

```
RubyGems Environment:
- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.5.1
- RUBY VERSION: 2.3.1 (2016-04-26 patchlevel 112) [x86_64-linux]
- INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1
- USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /root/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
- RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby
- EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin
- SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /root/.gem/specs
- SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/etc
- RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
  - ruby
  - x86_64-linux
- GEM PATHS:
  - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1
  - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/
  - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin
- GEM CONFIGURATION:
  - :update_sources => true
  - :verbose => true
  - :backtrace => false
  - :bulk_threshold => 1000
- REMOTE SOURCES:
  - https://rubygems.org/
- SHELL PATH:
  - /usr/kerberos/sbin
  - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin
  - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/bin
  - /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin
  - /usr/kerberos/bin
  - /usr/local/bin
  - /bin
  - /usr/bin
  - /usr/local/rvm/bin
  - /opt/dell/srvadmin/bin
  - /opt/dell/srvadmin/sbin
```

Any help or even things to try would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you elaborate on "use SASS via a php script". Post the line of code or command that causes the error.

Comment: $cmd = "echo \"" . $src . "\" | sass --scss --no-cache -s";

Comment: Where $src is the SCSS string to convert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user your php script is running as is seing the wrong ruby version, one for which you haven't installed sass for. Try having your script call these bash commands before any others to make sure it uses the one rvm has setup:

```
source "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm"
rvm use 2.3.1
```